# EntityFramework.Utilities multiple column update

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to speed up an update process I have and we're using EntityFramework.Utilities for that. The code is really straight forward but I can't find a way to update many tables at the same time.

```
EFBatchOperation.For(_repo, _repo.CityServices)
.Where(cs => cs.serviceid == serviceid && citiesFromDB.Contains(cs.cityid) && cs.status)
.Update(x => x.status, x => false);
//I would like to be able to call this method many times...
//.Update(x => x.updateddate, x => DateTime.Now);
```

Is there a way of doing this ? The UpdateAll method does not let me use a Where clause.

Comment: not really clear what You want to know. It seems that You're confused about what the update and updateAll do. UpdateAll just updates all the rows in the specified table, thus naturally it doesn't need the where clause.

If you want to update many table - Ctrl+C -> Ctrl+V, Right ?

Comment: Unfortunately what you are asking is not currently supported by the  EntityFramework.Utilities package.

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev.